# Trim() does not remove all whitespace characters

Tags: c#

`string x = "hello ​"; Console.WriteLine("\"" + x.Trim() + "\"");`

Output: "hello ​"
I want the output: "hello​"

How to deal with such symbols? This is the symbol U+200B

Comment: [U+8203](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+8203) is not whitespace. Are you sure that's the character you mean? Perhaps you meant [U+200B](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/200B)?

Comment: To remove all whitespace characters, including the non-breaking space, you can use the Replace() method in combination with regular expressions.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm talking about this symbol 
https://symbl.cc/en/200B/

Comment: I think you meant U+200B, which is Zero Width Space. Not whitespace according to `char.IsWhiteSpace` https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zo4Le9 also https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+200B shows the category as Format not Space Separator

Comment: One of the characters *specifically mentioned* in the documentation about [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: If you want to trim extra, non-whitespace characters (U+200B isn't) you can use the `Trim(Char[])` overload and specify the characters you want

Comment: Given that you've removed the claim that `char.IsWhiteSpace`, you might want to change the title... you certainly haven't given evidence that `Trim()` doesn't remove all whitespace characters.

Comment: @JonSkeet - evidence would be user eyesight it is a whitespace to the human eye, the technical specification doesn't reflect this

Comment: @RandRandom: I still think it's a misleading title, stemming from the original incorrect assertion. It gives the impression that `Trim()` isn't obeying its contract, which simply isn't the case.

Comment: @RandRandom - For a "zero width space" the human eye doesn't detect any space at all of any colour

Comment: @MartinSmith - but this is bascially what OP is looking for remove everything non human readable, there for OPs new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76372565/get-the-number-of-visible-characters-in-a-string

Comment: @JonSkeet - just in case you are interessted (see OPs new question)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    private readonly static string regExp = "((?=^)[\\s\\u200b]*)|([\\s\\u200b]*(?=$))";

    public static string TrimZSC(this string s)
        => Regex.Replace(s, regExp, "");
}
```

```
var x = " ​he  ​llo ​"; 
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(x.TrimZSC());
```

It will trim whitespace and 'Zero Space Character' at the end and at the beginning of the given string. Characters in between will remain (including zsc) - as they should (in the trim function).

Comment: Am I missing something or isn't `(?=^)` equivalent to simply `^`? Same for `$`.

Comment: @relatively_random in this case same result

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex` to write your own trim extension. For example, this trims all mark, separator and other categories at the beginning and end. `RegexOptions.Singleline` should make it behave like standard `Trim`.

I've split it into two expressions because a single one would have O(N^2) worst-case runtime. With `GeneratedRegex`, the performance shouldn't be terrible either.

```
internal static partial class MyTrimExtensions
{
    public static string TrimMarksSeparatorsOthers(this string toTrim)
    {
        var toTrimFront = TrimMarksSeparatorsOthersFrontRegex().Match(toTrim);
        if (toTrimFront.Length == toTrim.Length)
            return "";

        var toTrimBack = TrimMarksSeparatorsOthersBackRegex().Match(toTrim);
        return toTrim[toTrimFront.Length..toTrimBack.Index];
    }

    [GeneratedRegex("^[\\p{M}\\p{Z}\\p{C}]*", RegexOptions.Singleline)]
    private static partial Regex TrimMarksSeparatorsOthersFrontRegex();
    [GeneratedRegex("[\\p{M}\\p{Z}\\p{C}]*$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft)]
    private static partial Regex TrimMarksSeparatorsOthersBackRegex();
}
```